# Dynamic computed alias

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to update a component value dynamically from the controller, without explicitly passing the value through the template. The following hard-coded solution works:

```
foo: Em.computed.oneWay('bar')
```

however, I'm looking to have something like this:

```
slab: 'bar',
foo: Em.computed.oneWay(slab)
```

Its important that the values are bound together, and not just the initial value when the component starts up.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Can you provide an example on jsbin?

Answer (score 1):

Update January 2015: Coincidentally, I wrote a small addon for this a few days ago in response to an issue in the Ember Github. [This](https://github.com/gordonkristan/ember-computed-indirect) addon allows you to have dynamic computed properties. So this would now be your solution:

```
slab: 'bar',
foo: Ember.computed.indirect('slab')
```

That will keep the two bound together, so the `foo` property will always point at whichever property the `slab` value refers to.

---

Maybe something like this (taking from your example):

```
slab: function() {
    return mysteryString;
}.property(),

foo: undefined,

_slabObserver: null,
_slabObserverKey: null,
_slabDidChange: function() {
    // Remove the old observer
    if (this.get('_slabObserverKey')) {
        this.removeObserver(this, this.get('_slabObserverKey'), this.get('_slabObserver'));
    }

    // Create the new one
    this.set('_slabObserver', function() {
        // Update foo when the value whose key is held by 'slab' changes
        this.set('foo', this.get(this.get('slab')));
    });
    // Watch the property whose key is held by 'slab' and call the method we just created
    this.addObserver(this, this.get('slab'), this.get('_slabObserver'));

    // Hold the last key so we can remove the observer properly after it changes
    this.set('_slabObserverKey', this.get('slab'));
}.property('slab')
```

To walk through it:

1. The controller is created and `slab` is undefined. Something causes `slab` to change, triggering the `_slabDidChange` observer. (Note that we use `property` and not `observes` on `_slabDidChange` because the former would cause the function to get called too soon. [Source](http://alexmatchneer.com/blog/2013/01/12/everything-you-never-wanted-to-know-about-the-ember-run-loop/))
2. `_slabDidChange` fires. It skips removing the old observer because we haven't created one yet. It then adds a new observer that watches the property held by the `slab` property. It then stores the key and observer so we can remove them later.
3. `foo` is updated whenever the property we observed changes. In your example, anytime `bar` updates, `foo` updates.
4. If `slab` changes, step 2 repeats, only it removes the old observer first, as to not have conflicting updates to `foo`.

The idea is that you have to add the observer to the `bar` property manually. I haven't tested this, but the idea should be clear.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
slab: 'bar',
foo: Em.computed.oneWay(this.slab);
```

Comment: that doesn't work. Also, i should probably be clear that my example was the simple case. slab: is actually a property function `slab: function(){}.property() since I need to generate the string 'bar'

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can only do this with a computed property:

```
foo: function(key, value) {
        var slab = this.get('slab');

        if (arguments.length > 1) {
            this.set(slab, value);
        }

        return this.get(slab);
    }.property('slab')
```

For `oneWay`, you will have to change `this.set(slab, value);` or just remove the whole `if`.